# How fast should my WLAN be?

Tags: wireless-networking

As the first step of setting up a more relevant model, I tried sending data as fast as I could between two Raspberry Pis, both sitting on my desk, both linked to the same pretty good wifi router. Using C++, I opened a TCP socket on one Pi and poured in 20 MB (of zeroes) as fast as it would go. On the other Pi I also opened a socket, on which I received (and bit-bucketed) data as fast as it would come out.

It turned out to take about 8.7 sec, giving around 2.3 MB/sec. Buffer sizes didn't seem to make much difference.

I expected a lot faster. What am I missing?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* -- (1) You are not using high-performance hardware. Clarify which RPi and WiFI HW you are using, and determine exactly how the Wifi peripheral is connected (e.g. through USB?). (2) *"Using C++, I opened a TCP socket ... as fast as it would go"* -- TCP is a reliable protocol that imposes significant additional overhead per Ethernet frame and additional packets for transfers. UDP would be a better choice for measuring throughput. (3) How efficient is your code? How many bytes of payload do you try to send or receive per syscall? IOW too many syscalls impact performance.

Comment: If you want to measure network performance on devices you have terminal access to, use real tools like `nload` and iPerf3. The reality is you might know how to open a TCP socket via C++ but honestly you will not be able to measure things as well as those existing tools. To use them you basically launch them and then do something like a file transfer between devices and look at what they report.

Comment: The goal is to achieve high throughput from one RPi to another over the internet. But I wanted to start with a simpler case, i.e. on my desktop. I used TCP for reliability.

Comment: Thanks for constructive help, sawdust. (1) RPis 3B with on-board wifi, Airport Extreme. (2) I need reliability. If I add my own error check/retransmit protocol on top of UDP, is that better than TCP?  (3) I tried various buffer sizes (bytes per syscall) without much effect on throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Given specific hardware with a producer stated maximum capability of "S" (Mega)bits per second you will not ever get 100% of that - you should expect slowdown for a number of factors.

Generally, for TCP/IP anything near 70% of S is achievable; assuming ALL the involved devices have good enough computing power.
With careful optimization for specific tasks you might get (slightly) higher throughput. e.g. using "UDP" on Ethernet hardware.

**Factors that reduce the likelihood of good speed:**

- Relative weight of protocol overhead / Using "small" packets
- Lower spec than standard cabling, cable sees electromagnetic
  interference
- WLAN, Wireless, Bluetooth - e.g. any radio based transfers
- For radio: Long distance between radio nodes, interference from other nodes, air humidity level, walls, trees or other
  obstacles in the middle of the radio path.
- ... more.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: Thanks for constructive help, Hannu, but I read Wikipedia too. I know all that. But I'm getting less than 10% of "S" right on my desktop. I used TCP for reliability; would I be better off rolling my own error check/retransmission protocol? (I doubt it.) Larger buffer sizes don't improve throughput. Again, what am I missing?